# How to sync files matching glob pattern like `foo*/bar*/yaz*.gz`

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to sync a set of files which are found by the linux fileglob `foo*/bar*/yaz*.gz`.

The standard rsync trick of `--include='yaz*.gz' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs` does work, but it is quite slow since there are *many* other uninteresting directories and files that it finds.

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: How do I efficiently rsync files matching a glob pattern like `foo*/bar*/yaz*.gz`?  This is over a network.

Comment: did you try an alternative like find to match the glob file pattern, then call rsync for each match?

Comment: As mentioned this for a remote sync.  I suppose that `ssh me@remote 'ls /path/to/foo*/bar*/yaz*.gz'` could get the remote files.  I was hoping for something a little more elegant.  :-)